# How to change a class variable in PHP?

Tags: undefined, php

I'm sure there is an easy answer to this question, but for the life of me, I can't find it.  I'm using PHP5 and I'm trying to change the value of a class variable, but it doesn't appear to change.  For example, I have something like this:

```
<?php

include_once "../includes/global.php";

loadDAOs('yweightGroups','yweightCourses','yweightUsers','user','yweightData');



class yweight {

private $header_includes;
private $user;
private $yweightUser;

//Description:
//  Constructor.
//Parameters:
//  -none-
//Returns:
//  -nothing-
function __construct() {
    global $r_action;
    global $r_page;

    $this->user = login_required(); 

    if(!$this->user || empty($this->user)){
        die();
        goHome();   
    }

    $this->header_includes = "";

    if(isset($r_action)) {
        $this->$r_action(); 
    }
    else if (isset($r_page)) {
        $this->$r_page();   
    }
    else {
        $this->draw();  
    }       
}

//Description:
//  Draws the YWeight page
//Parameters:
//  -none-
//Returns:
//  -nothing-
function draw() {
    global $r_page;     
    global $colorDAO;
    global $yweightUsersDAO;

    ob_start();
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="./yweight.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yweight.css" />
    <?php

    $this->header_includes .= ob_get_clean();

    $col = $colorDAO->read(17);
    print_top("",$this->header_includes,"resources","",$col->value,$col->fontcolor);

    $users = $yweightUsersDAO->GetByUserID($this->user->id);

    if(!$users){
        echo "<div class='msg_failed'>You are not authorized to view this page.</div>";
        die();
    }

    $this->yweightUser = $users;
    echo serialize($this->yweightUser[0]);
    ?>
    <div id="yweight_area"></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        <?php
        if($users[0]->yweightUsers_intern == 0)
            echo "drawPage('main_participant');";
        else
            echo "drawPage('main_intern');";
        ?>
    </script>
    <?php   
    print_bottom();
    echo ob_get_clean();

}           


//Description:
//  Draws the main intern page.
//Parameters:
//  -none-
//Returns:
//  -nothing-
function main_intern() {
    ob_start();
    echo "hello intern";
    echo ob_get_clean();
}

//Description:
//  Draws the main participant page.
//Parameters:
//  -none-
//Returns:
//  -nothing-
function main_participant() {
    global $yweightDataDAO;
    ob_start();
    $this->yweightUser = $this->yweightUser[0];
    echo serialize($this->yweightUser);
    ?>
    <div id="banner_div">
        <img class="banner" width="927" src="images/ParticipantsMain.jpg" />
        <img id="tracker_btn" class="std_btn" src="images/trackerButton.png" />
        <img id="summary_btn" class="std_btn" src="images/summaryButton.png" />
        <img id="requirements_btn" class="std_btn" src="images/reqButton.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="discussion_board_input_div">
        <textarea id="discussion_board_input" />
        <?php
        echo build_btn("green",100,25,"Submit","","","","",
            'submit_post()',"margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px; float:right;");
        ?>
    <div class="clear_floats" />
    </div>
    <div id="discussion_board_div">

    </div>
    <?php
    echo ob_get_clean();
}

function submit_post(){
    global $yweightDataDAO;
    global $userDAO;
    global $r_post;
    echo serialize($this->yweightUser);
    $userDataID = $yweightDataDAO->GetByUserID($this->yweightUser->user_id);

    if($userDataID){
        $userData = $yweightDataDAO->read($userDataID);
        $userDiscussion = unserialize($userData->yweightData_discussionBoard);
    }

    $userDiscussion[$this->user->firstName .  time()] = $r_post;

    $userData->yweightData_discussionBoard = serialize($userDiscussion);

    $yweightDataDAO->save($userData);
}

}


$recs = new yweight();

?>
```

submit_post() is an ajax called function.  The error I'm getting is that it says $this->yweightUser is undefined.  I didn't orignally include all of the code because I thought that I was just misunderstanding how class variables are declared.

Comment: You've included the class, but not the code that calls the class functions.  Could you add a small snippet that shows how you instantiate foo and call echoVariable()?

Comment: You have syntax errors in the code, such as __construct missing the opening braces. I fixed it up and tried it on my localserver and it worked fine, you don't have errors when running the code?

Comment: Is this the actual code? Your constructor will not be called by PHP, because the keyword for that requires a double underscore and parentheses (`__construct()`). Please show the **actual** code.

Comment: You should always specific the visibility, even if it's public by default.

Comment: If you fix the syntax errors, it works.  http://codepad.org/TxuVluUc

Comment: People, please stop editing the question and adding code that isn't there. That's not helpful, especially when the problem might lie there. Edit: now OP added it himself, that's fine. ;-)

Comment: @Rocket why not put this as an answer - as unless I missed something, this IS the answer :o)

Comment: @SteveH: Its already been added as an answer by others.  I'll let them get the rep :-)

Comment: @SteveH the syntax errors seem not to be the problem, as OP states _It will echo "hello world."_ The real problem might lie in the fact that this is not the actual code, because with a syntax error it won't print that much. :-)

Comment: @CodeCaster perhaps he just forgot to 'update' that part of the question (that it now works) :o)

Comment: for future reference 'php -l <scriptname.php>' will tell you if the code has any syntax errors.

Comment: I apologize for not originally including the actual code.  I thought it was just something I overlooked in declaring class variables.  I have now posted the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. Use `__construct`. Two (`_ _`) underscores. Your `fooVariable` is never getting set. After it gets set it works fine.

**Update:** You only set `$this->yweightUser` in your function `draw()` method. If you don't call `draw()` before `ajax_post()` or w/e, it will not be defined.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't the actual code.  I have updated the question with my actual code.  I just thought I didn't fully understand how to declare class variables.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, fix the syntax errrors and it works, 2 underscores for the constructor and opening brace for the constructor and also brackets for arguments:

```
  class foo {

protected $fooVariable;

function __construct () {
  $this->fooVariable = "hello world";
  $this->changeVariable();
}

function changeVariable(){
  $this->fooVariable = "goodbye world";
  $this->echoVariable();
}

function echoVariable(){
  echo $this->fooVariable;
}
}

$foo = new foo();
```